# Get sysuptime snmp to format "days,hours,minutes"

Tags: date, snmp, date-format, uptime

Through using SNMP protocol i can get the sysuptime of a device for example `1714656039`

How can i convert this into `x days y minutes z seconds`?

A reference of what type of data is the `1714656039` can be found [here](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3). It is actually

> The time (in hundredths of a second) since the network management
>   portion of the system was last re-initialized.

Is [this](https://www.thedarktimes.us/wordpress/uncategorized/converting-snmp-timeticks-to-time) something useful?

Comment: Then what have you tried when that useful link is found? Isn't it giving you the correct answer?

Comment: net-snmputils do it for you by default: `snmpget -v2c -c public123 somedevice sysUpTime.0`  -> ``DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (3540403222) 409 days, 18:27:12.22 . Or use programming language of your choice to tweak output format.